# paso por referencia con punteros

Tags: c++, funciones, punteros

Ayuda por favor, no puedo pasar el puntero a la funcion. me dice que tengo un error diciendo " Usando la memoria sin inicializar 'dir_numeros'" ya lo inicio en 0 y de la misma forma tengo un error no se que puedo hacer.

uso visual studio 2019

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Deberiamos ver tu codigo para poder ayudarte...

Comment: O pasas por referencia o pasas por dirección (puntero), las dos cosas a la vez no existe. ¿Por qué no pones el código para que veamos a qué te refieres?

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar explicarte un poco cómo funciona el tema de pasar por referencia un puntero, a ver si puede ser que te refieras a eso.

```
int suma(int *n1, int *n2)   //Le pasamos como parametros dos posiciones de memoria, la de la variable de n1 y de n2
{
    *n1 = *n1 + *n2;
    return *n1;
}

int main()
{
    int *n1 =new int; //Aqui se declara el puntero, por lo que n1 = posicion de memoria
    *n1 = 1;          //Aqui le decimos el valor que se encuentra en la posicion de memoria de n1
    int n2 = 2;       //Aqui le decimos basicamente que la variable n2 es igual al valor de entero 2

    printf("El resultado es [%i]", suma(n1, &n2));  // Como n1 es una posicion de memoria no hace 
                                                    // falta ponerle ni * ni &, sin embargo a n2 hay 
                                                    // que ponerle &, ya que eso significa que le 
                                                    // pasamos la referencia de n2
    delete(n1);
    return 0;
}
```